# Convert console application to windows service

Tags: c#, service, signalr

I have a console application which I am running SignalR with. I am attempting to convert it into a windows service application.

I simply swapped out the `Main` method with

```
static void Main()
{
    var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new MyService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
}
```

and added a service class which is simply:

```
namespace Services
{
    partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }

        public MyService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            const string url = "https://localhost:8080";
            using (SignalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                          //TODO: Add Logging
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            SignalR.Dispose();
        }
          }
}
```

But now when I try to run the installer I get the error:

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Code \MyCode\Services\bin\Debug\MyService.exe' or
>   one of its dependencies. A n attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format..

Is there any easy way to debug this message? Or does anyone have any idea of what I may have missed?

Comment: I've used and recommend using https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running the installation? I'd wager a guess that you're registering a 32-bit compiled application with the 64 bit installer or vice versa

In other words, running:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe <My x64 DLL/EXE>
```

or:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe <My x86 DLL/EXE>
```

Comment: I was actually going to `%projDirectory%\bin\Debug` and running `installutil.exe`. Still the same issue trying from both of those directories though.

Comment: ok; instead of typing just installutil.exe, force it to the correct one using the paths in my answer. One will work, one will fail.

Comment: Sorry. This did work. I had incorrectly typed one of the directories. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You miss create the installer in the service
In your service in design view, right click and select Add Installer or similar, my vs is in spanish.
This add a new component to the project `ProjectInstaller` with two components inside `serviceProcessInstaller1` and `serviceInstaller1` in this components you must assing some propertys wich confure the behavior of the instalaction, Service Account,Name, Description, etc.
The you can run the installutil.exe for install, w/o this installutil does nothing

Comment: The installed was added when I got this issue. The solution was found in the accepted answer.